# Pinpoint specific file and version in ClearQuest

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearquest

We have a CR which is figured out to be fixed as part of an enhancement. This enhancement has a activities with huge number of files checked-in. Now if I make this CR invalid duplicate of the enhancement, the client has to scan through the list of files in that activity to figure out the actual file.
My manager suggested rolling back the change with one activity, adding the change back in with another activity and attach only the adding back activity to the CR and close it. 
I am just wondering if there is no way to easily pinpoint the specific file and version to the client instead of all this mess.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the list of activities referenced by your CR, you can script the search with some:

```
cleartool descr -l activity:myActivity@myPVob
```

and display the relevant files and versions once you have described the right activity.